# Create a buffer to select underlying features in GeoServer

Tags: javascript, openlayers, buffer

I created a  web page that displays a map by some more information and I want to add the ability to create a buffer centered on the position that I click on.

My idea is to select or change the symbols of the features that are placed under the buffer. I have no idea how I should do this.

My page html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>OpenLayers map preview</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
       href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers3/ol.css"  
       type="text/css">
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers3/ol.js" 
       type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  <li>
      <a>Filter:</a>
      <input type="text" size="80" id="filter"/>
      <a 
        id="updateFilterButton" 
        href="#" 
        onClick="updateFilter()" 
        title="Apply filter">Apply</a>
      <a
        id="resetFilterButton" 
        href="#" 
        onClick="resetFilter()" 
        title="Reset filter">Reset</a>
    </li>
 <div id="layertree">
 <h5>Click on layer nodes below to change their properties.</h5>
 <ul>
    <li><!-- nmtoken edit added missing li -->
    <ul>
        <li><span>Food insecurity layer</span>
          <fieldset id="layer10">
            <label class="checkbox" for="visible10">
              <input id="visible10" class="visible" type="checkbox"/>visibility
            </label>
            <label>opacity</label>
            <input class="opacity" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01"/>
          </fieldset>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="nodelist">
    <em>Click on the map to get feature info</em>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var pureCoverage = false;   
      var bounds = [5720947.7865, 4259576.5416,
                5721755.0394, 4260363.5763];
    var untiled = new ol.layer.Image({
      source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms/' ,
      params: { LAYERS: 'cite:polygon2' }
    })
  });
  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }), new ol.layer.Group({
        layers: [untiled]
      })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.40570, 8.81566]),
      zoom: 4
    })
  });
  map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize());
  function bindInputs (layerid, layer) {
    var visibilityInput = $(layerid + ' input.visible');
    visibilityInput.on('change', function() {
      layer.setVisible(this.checked);
    });
    visibilityInput.prop('checked', layer.getVisible());

    var opacityInput = $(layerid + ' input.opacity');
    opacityInput.on('input change', function() {
      layer.setOpacity(parseFloat(this.value));
    });
    opacityInput.val(String(layer.getOpacity()));
  }
  map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer, i) {
    bindInputs('#layer' + i, layer);
    if (layer instanceof ol.layer.Group) {
      layer.getLayers().forEach(function(sublayer, j) {
        bindInputs('#layer' + i + j, sublayer);
      });
    }
  });

  $('#layertree li > span').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('fieldset').toggle();
  }).siblings('fieldset').hide();
            map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = "Loading... please wait...";
    var view = map.getView();
    var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
    var source = untiled.get('visible') ? untiled.getSource() : tiled.getSource();
    var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate, viewResolution, view.getProjection(),
      {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 'FEATURE_COUNT': 50});
    if (url) {
      document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
    }
  });

  function updateFilter(){
    if (pureCoverage) {
      return;
    }

    var filter = document.getElementById('filter').value;
    // by default, reset all filters
    var filterParams = {

      'FEATUREID': null
    };
 {
        filterParams["FEATUREID"] = filter;
      }
      // merge the new filter definitions
      map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
        untiled.getSource().updateParams(filterParams);
      });
    }

    function resetFilter() {
      if (pureCoverage) {
        return;
      }
      document.getElementById('filter').value = "";
      updateFilter();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score -1):

You're gonna need to use WPS, Take a look at [this](https://run.unl.pt/handle/10362/11670?locale=en). It has all your answers.

Comment: thank a lot
but until now i just added wps request builder to my geoserver
i find the buffer processes but  that book did not explained how shuld use it and work with it in web page
 i jast have a xml file and i dont know how shuld i use it...